# Visa for Amsterdam

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, south-african-citizens

Please can someone assist me? My daughter has a South African passport and is living and working in London on a British ancestral visa. She wants to travel to Amsterdam and also to Paris for a weekend. Where does she apply for these visas?

Answer (score 2):

She can apply for a visa from [the Netherlands](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/applying-for-a-short-stay-schengen-visa/united-kingdom) (at [a VFS Global office](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Netherlands/UK/index.html) in London, Edinburgh, or Manchester) or [France](https://uk.ambafrance.org/Informations-about-visas) (at a [TLScontact office](https://fr.tlscontact.com/gb/splash.php) in London and Edinburgh). Those links will have all the instructions and forms to fill out.

She should apply to the country that is the main destination for her first trip. If she receives a multiple entry visa, she can use that for subsequent trips to the Schengen area as long as she doesn't exceed the dates and number of days limitations on the visa and [the 90/180 days rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work).